# How can i make jmeter run all thread group before repeat?

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group with 2 http requests, the first one is for the user to log in and have two regular expression extractor so I can extract the credentials.

the second http request should use those credentials in the header.

This is all working except that jmeter is executing all login requests, and after that executes the second request.

I was expecting the login request to execute and after that the second request, and then repeat the whole thing.

Any sugestion?
[image: the test plan]

[image: view result tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to repeat your test flow set in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)

> Each thread will execute the test plan in its entirety and completely independently of other test threads. Multiple threads are used to simulate concurrent connections to your server application.

`Number of Threads` = 1 and `Loop Count` with the number of times you want to repeat.

This way you will execute the samplers sequentially.

If you set `Number of Threads` above 1 it will execute test flows in parallel, if you need it you will have to use [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer).

> The purpose of the SyncTimer is to block threads until X number of threads have been blocked, and then they are all released at once.

Comment: My goal is to test my server with multiple users at the same time, so you say i need the SyncTimer?

Comment: @JTavares95 After Login request add `Test Action` and under it add `Synchronizing Timer` set in Timer Number of users equal to number of threads

Comment: at this moment i have
.login request
.test
..synchronizing time (Number simulated users: 50, timeout: 5000)
.listwallets request
but it seems that only execute the test 1 time, and i want 50 concurrent runs

Comment: @JTavares95 in Thread Group set Number of Threads = 50 also, notice also that timeout can be 0